# Bietole e barbabietole, biete e bietine

Tags: word-usage, single-words

Buongiorno,

Volevo chiedere come mai in italiano le parole "bietole" e "barbabietole" si assomigliano, pur riferendosi queste parole a prodotti agricoli diversi. Da quanto capisco, queste parole si riferiscono a piantare diverse, la prima delle quali ha le foglie che sono commestibili, e per la seconda il tubero è commestibile.

Allora vorrei chiedere, da dove deriva la somiglianza tra queste due parole. C'è un significato latino di bietola, da dove deriva questa parola. E soprattutto vorrei sapere perché "barba", come se barbabietola fosse una bella con la barba.

Grazie.

EDIT: c'è alcun rapporto etimologico tra bieta, bietina, e bietola e barbabietola?

Grazie.

Comment: piantare = piante? bella = bietola? Jack, potresti per cortesia rileggere le tue domande prima di inviarle (e magari disattivare il correttore automatico)?

Comment: Il Treccani dà *bieta* come antico o regionale per *bietola* che, a sua volta, è sinonimo di *barbabietola*. Ovviamente *bietina* è un diminutivo di *bieta*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Secondo la [voce “Bietola” su Wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bietola), la bietola è una varietà di barbabietola (*Beta vulgaris*). Se ne mangiano foglie e gambi.

Esistono molte varietà di *Beta vulgaris*, una delle quali è la [barbabietola da zucchero](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbabietola_da_zucchero).

Tenderei a escludere che della barbabietola si mangino le radici: credo che siano disgustose. Ma, siccome alcune varietà hanno più alta concentrazione di saccarosio, sono coltivate per ricavarne lo zucchero.

Sulla questione del disgusto ho un'esperienza personale. Da bambino ho vissuto in una zona di campagna dove c'erano vaste coltivazioni di barbabietola da zucchero e anche uno zuccherificio. Un sottoprodotto della lavorazione erano le “polpe” che venivano adoperate come mangime per le vacche. Nel fatale periodo seguente, il latte (che allora si comperava localmente) aveva un sapore terribile.